# jQuery fadeIn.css()?

Tags: jquery, css, styles, fadein

How can I make the .css() propertys fadeIn?
page: http://arnoldsktm.zxq.net/

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#1, #2, #3, #4').hide();
        $('#1').fadeIn(1000, function(){
            $('#2').fadeIn(500, function(){
                $('#3').fadeIn(1000, function(){
                    $('#4').fadeIn(1000, function(){
                        $('#4').css({
                            'text-shadow':'0px 0px 10px red',
                            'text-decoration':'underline'
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

This $('#4').css({});

http://jsfiddle.net/F9xkS/2

Comment: You can use jQuery animate

Comment: If your #4 is hidden why not to set text-shadow and other styles for it and just later fade it in?

Comment: text-decoration doesn't animate, but you could use a border-bottom instead. text-shadow should animate, although you might need to use jQuery UI or make your own step function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery cannot animate non-numeric values per [its documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animation-properties).  You could try `.animate` instead of `.css`, but I suspect it won't work with these.

Instead you're better off relying on CSS3 transitions and just adding a class:

```
#4 {
    -webkit-transition: text-shadow 1s;
    transition: text-shadow 1s;
}
#4.shown {
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px red;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

$("#4").fadeIn(... function () { $(this).addClass('shown');
```

Note that `text-decoration` is [not an animatable property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties).  It wouldn't make sense to animate the underline.  Instead maybe you can underline it ahead of time so the underline is also faded in.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/F9xkS/6/

```
a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: text-shadow .3s;
    transition: text-decoration: .3s;
}
.glow {
    text-shadow:0px 0px 10px red;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

$('#1, #2, #3, #4').hide();

$('#1').fadeIn(1000, function () {
    $('#2').fadeIn(500, function () {
        $('#3').fadeIn(1000, function () {
            $('#4').fadeIn(1000, function () {
                $('#4').addClass('glow');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using CSS transitions. For example:

```
#4
{
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms;
    -o-transition: all 200ms;
    -ms-transition: all 200ms;
    transition: all 200ms;
}
```

Comment: $('#4').animate({
        'text-shadow':'0px 0px 10px red',
        'text-decoration':'underline'
       }); isnt working

Comment: When using CSS transitions, you don't have to use animate() function. Instead, just set the desired properties with css() function - the same as in your original example. Animation is handled by CSS behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Just set styles to it before fading it, see [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F9xkS/2/)

```
#4 {
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px red;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```